# QGIS how to compute a trendline of two point lines?

Tags: qgis, point, line

Does anyone know how to compute a trendline for two lines of points? I have two lines of points of a 10 km long urban road. 1st line is one driving direction and the 2nd line of points ist the other driving direction.

Is there a way to get a trendline of these both point lines also as a point line?

Thanks!!

Comment: explain please. what you mean by trendline? a line joing end points? best fit line? line that rejects small changes and keep major "trend" in your poly line?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by "point line" (line showing a generalized trend of points), however you may use the Vector menu>Geometry Tools>Simplify Geometries tool.

1. You first need to either manually connect the dots from a new line shapefile or use the  Points2One plugin
2. Once you have the line feature you may run the Simplify Geometries tool on it

[image]

Another option would be to run some sort of linear regression algorithm on the the xy values to generate the trend line (slope).